# In vhdl, how to create a to_line function that works for all strings?

Tags: vhdl

In vhdl, how to create a generic function that takes a string and returns a line containing that string?   Everytime, I try to do this I get syntax errors...

Here's my problem:

```sh
$ vcom -2002 test1.vhd

** Error: test1.vhd(44): (vcom-1047) 
Actual (string literal) for class variable formal 
"path_in2" is not a variable.

** Error: test1.vhd(44): Function call returns 
type (error); expecting type std.TEXTIO.LINE.

** Note: test1.vhd(50): VHDL Compiler exiting
End time: 08:38:08 on Mar 23,2022, Elapsed time: 0:00:00
Errors: 2, Warnings: 0
```

```vhdl
use std.textio.all;

entity test1 is
end entity;

architecture beh of test1 is
```

```vhdl
        procedure join_path(
            variable path_in1 :in  line;
            variable path_in2 :in  line;
            variable path_out :out line         
        ) is
            variable mout :line;
            variable has_slash :boolean := false;
        begin
            path_out := null;
            
            if (path_in1 = null) then
                path_out := path_in2;
                return;
            end if;
            
            if (path_in1.all(path_in1'length-1) = '/' or
                path_in1.all(path_in1'length-1) = '\'
            ) then
                has_slash := true;
            end if;         
            write(mout, path_in1.all);
            if (not has_slash) then
                write(mout, '/');
            end if;
            write(mout, path_in2.all);
            path_out := mout;
            return;
        end procedure;
```

```vhdl
    impure function to_line(constant s :string) 
    return line is 
        variable m:line;
    begin
        write(m, s);
        return m;
    end function;
```

```vhdl
begin

   process 
       variable projdir :line := null;
       variable mempath :line := null;
   begin
       join_path(
           path_in1 => projdir,
           path_in2 => to_line("mem.txt"), --LINE 44
           path_out => mempath
       );

       report mempath.all;

       wait;
   end process;
   
end architecture;
```

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 4.2.2.1 Formal parameters list "In a subprogram call, the actual designator (see 6.5.7.1) associated with a formal parameter of class **signal** shall be a name denoting a signal. The actual designator associated with a formal of class **variable** shall be a name denoting a variable. The actual designator associated with a formal of class constant shall be an expression. ..." The basic issue here is that a function call is an expression (a formula for producing a value of type).

Comment: You'd want a procedure that assigns an inout parameter of type line instead of a function, here simple enough to do inline  in the process instead `variable mem_init: line; begin write(mem_init, string'("mem.txt")); join_path( ...path_in2 => mem_init, ...`.  (And that analyzes as does your answer.)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get **to_line()** function to work... but it would be much nicer if vhdl let you do that because it requres less variables.

My work around was as follows:

```vhdl
   process 
       variable projdir :line := null;
       variable mempath :line := null;
       variable memfile :line := null;
   begin
       write(memfile, string'("mem.txt"));

       join_path(
           path_in1 => projdir,
           path_in2 => memfile,
           path_out => mempath
       );

       report mempath.all;

       wait;
   end process;
```

Comment: As the error correctly states, the return value of a function is not itself a variable. It must be first assigned to a variable object as you have done. If you think this is a VHDL limitation, why not raise an [issue](https://gitlab.com/IEEE-P1076/VHDL-Issues/-/issues?sort=created_date&state=opened) against the LRM?

Comment: variable m:line?  it isn't a variable object?

Comment: Yes, your original post uses the function return directly.  The answer uses a variable object to store the function return value.

Comment: The procedure call to join_path requires that variable. Note that an access type must be class variable.